# When including a graphic using text in LaTeX, "fi" and "ff" are not printed after compiling. How can I change this?

Tags: graphics, errors, pdf, include

In my study, I include PDF graphics as images in order to receive high resolution graphics. These PDF graphics are initially created in Power Point, printed as PDF there, and then included in the document like in the code below.

In the original PDF that is included, "fi"s and "ff"s are shown (as in "Definition"), but after inclusion in LaTeX and compilation, they are lost. As I already include a PDF, I cannot add anything in the LaTeX code to avoid this, I guess. What can I do?

The PDF is located in the same folder as "SimulationProcess.pdf".
I attach a partial screenshot of both the original PDF and the look after compilation.

[image: Original]

[image: Compiled]

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[bindingoffset=1cm,margin=3cm]{geometry}

...

\begin{document}

...


\begin{figure}[here]

\centering 

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{SimulationProcess} 

\label{fig:SimulationProcess}

\end{figure}
```

Comment: This can happen with some font combination. But as your example is not complete and the graphic is missing it is difficult to say more.

Comment: This might actually be similar in nature to [Hyphen sporadically appearing In enumerated list](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/214120/5764). Perhaps loading `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` might solve the problem. Do you have this showing up in the image itself, or only when you include the image in your document?

Comment: @Werner: I don't think that this is the problem. Bettina is including a pdf, inputenc has nothing to do here. It is probably this problem: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50829/ligatures-in-figures-and-pdftex/50834#50834

Comment: The answer in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50829/ligatures-in-figures-and-pdftex/50834#50834 solved it - thank you, Ulrike!